# Canasta - initial pickup

Tags: canasta

Is it permissable to table initial meld and then pick up discard pile with a wild card and one natural card which matches the one on the top of the discard pile all in the same turn?  Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not allowed.

Drawing cards, whether from the deck or the discard pile, is always the first step in a turn. You cannot play any melds until after you have drawn.

> After drawing, but before discarding, you may sometimes be able to play some cards from your hand face up on the table.

From https://www.pagat.com/rummy/canasta.html